# matlab create title for each boxplot

Tags: matlab

Here is a problem:

I have a boxplot but there is no easy way to name each of these small boxes.
Here is an example:

```
boxplot(rand(10,3))
```

will draw 3 of this boxes, but will the title for each of these boxes are 1, 2, 3 and I need some more meaningful things.

I have one [idea](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html), how to achieve it,

```
load carsmall
boxplot(MPG,Origin)
```

But this require to restructure my data and create additional columns with titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
boxplot(rand(10,3), 'labels', {'a','b','c'})
```

do what you need?